# Unknown property 'GoogleChartsController.getdynamiclist' in salesforce VF and Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am developing **Easy Visualforce Charts with JavaScript Remoting & Google Charts API.**. I this example I am looking to keep drop down list and trying to provide ColumnChart and LineChart.

> Unknown property 'GoogleChartsController.getdynamiclist'

**GoogleChartsController**

```
global with sharing class GoogleChartsController{
    public String selectedVal{get;set;} 

    @RemoteAction
    global static Opportunity[] loadOpps() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ExpectedRevenue, Amount FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 20];
    }

    global GoogleChartsController(){}

    global List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('ColumnChart','ColumnChart'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('LineChart','LineChart'));
        return options;
    }
}
```

and **VPPage**

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleChartsController" sidebar="false">
     <!-- Google API inclusion -->
    <apex:includeScript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Google Charts + Javascript Remoting" subtitle="Demoing - Opportunities by Exepected Revenue" />
    <div id="chartBlock">
        <script>
            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

            function initCharts(){
                GoogleChartsController.loadOpps(
                    function(result, event){
                        // load Column chart
                        var visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
                         // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                         data.addColumn('string', 'Opportunity');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Expected Revenue');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Amount'); 

                         // add rows from the remoting results
                         for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){
                            var r = result[i];
                            data.addRow([r.Name, r.ExpectedRevenue, r.Amount]); 
                          }
                        // all done, lets draw the chart with some options to make it look nice.
                        visualization.draw(data, {legend : {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 10}}, width:window.innerWidth,vAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10}},hAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10},showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}});
                }, {escape:true});
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!getdynamiclist}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>    

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to use like below: This works fine.

```
<apex:form >
      <apex:selectList size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}"></apex:selectOptions>
      </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```